# How to return only one variable in multi return function in GO?

Tags: go, return

Hi I have this function which I want to return a [docker.APIContainer](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#APIContainers) and an error (nil if no errors), but in case of error what should I return in docker.APIContainer ?

this is the code

```
func GetContainersRunningImage(imagename string, tag string) ([]docker.Container,string) {
   logFields := log.Fields{

       "handler": "get service",
   }
   client, err := docker.NewTLSClient(sconf.DockConf.Endpoint, sconf.DockConf.Cert, sconf.DockConf.Key, sconf.DockConf.Ca)
   if err != nil {
      log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("TLSClient could not be created: %s", err)
      return _,err.Error()
   }
}
```

what should I add instead of _? Am I obliged to create a `var contarray []docker.Container` and return it? or is there another way

Comment: @Jakumi I tried to return nil in an int type just trying to see if I can return it in all types but I got an error: cannot use nil as type int in return argument
So I thought that it will give the same error in types other than string

Comment: @Jakumi just for testing I created a structure in go playground and tried to return a nil value I got an error https://play.golang.org/p/RytEExB6bv

Comment: @diegosouza Returning `nil` is best practice for a pointer return value (and can be used only for pointer values). For concrete types its up to you, it can be some meaningful value like in io.Readers `Read` method, or some "incorrect" value like 0 or -1 for int return value etc. See https://play.golang.org/p/70ilkDhcQc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return nil, err.Error()
```

[goreturns](https://github.com/sqs/goreturns) will do this for you automatically - `0` for int and `""` for string etc.

Comment: just for testing I created a structure in go playground and tried to return a nil value I got an error https://play.golang.org/p/RytEExB6bv

Comment: You are misunderstand how to properly return a `nil` value. Types in Go have different `nil` value - `0` for int, `""` for string, `nil` for pointers... Now to your code on playground, there are 2 options: https://play.golang.org/p/tz_is19Lvn or https://play.golang.org/p/70ilkDhcQc. For the first one, you expect to return a `nil` struct, this is not possible in Go, so we need to return a struct with no data `Fs{}`. On the other hand, pointer to a struct can be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

`GetContainersRunningImage` returns multiple values: a `[]docker.Container` and a `string`, which means you have to return two values with exactly the same type signatures, or `nil` in case you do not want to return a concrete value.

Because you are handling the error case it's ok to return a `nil` value in case of an error:

```
if err != nil {
      log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("TLSClient could not be created: %s", err)
      return nil, err.Error()
}
```

But you have to return a value at the end of the function in case you don't receive an error. In this case the type signature of the return function should be of type: `[]docker.Container`, `string`.

That's why in Go the idiomatic way of a function return argument is the value and an error if an error has occurred. Because you are handling the error separately in an if statement which returns two values: `nil` instead of the value and the `error` type, the final return should be the type value and `nil` for error.

```
func GetContainersRunningImage(imagename string, tag string) ([]docker.Container,string) {
   var contarray []docker.Container

   logFields := log.Fields{

       "handler": "get service",
   }
   client, err := docker.NewTLSClient(sconf.DockConf.Endpoint, sconf.DockConf.Cert, sconf.DockConf.Key, sconf.DockConf.Ca)
   if err != nil {
      log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("TLSClient could not be created: %s", err)
      return nil, err.Error()
   }

   return contarray, nil
}
```

Other possibility is to use the `_`(underscore) variable to disregard one of the return values, but this needs to happen on variable assignment.

Comment: just for testing I created a structure in go playground and tried to return a nil value I got an error https://play.golang.org/p/RytEExB6bv